# Logging Window system

Tags: python, controller, pyqt

(I originally asked this on Stack Overflow and was directed here)

So I have 2 classes, one is a PyQT window widget, and the other class is a stack which holds a dictionary pointing to all of the window objects.

Log Window:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from Log.Controllers.Routines.log_get_next_default_index_routine import get_next_nefault_index


class LogWindow(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self,
                 model=None,
                 index=get_next_default_index(),
                 title=None):

        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.index = index
        self.title = title
        self.set_title(title)

    def set_model(self,model):
        if model is not None:
            self.model = model
        else:
            self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.setModel(self.model)

    def set_index(self,index):
        if index is not None:
            self.index = index
        else:
            self.index = log_coordinator.get_next_default_index()

    def set_title(self,title):
        if title is not None:
            self.setWindowTitle(title)
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle('Log Window %s' % self.index)
```

Log Stack:

```
class LogWindowStack():
    def __init__(self,index=None,log_window=None, log_window_bundle=None):
        self.stack = {}
        self.default_index_counter = 0

        self.populate_index(index,log_window,log_window_bundle)

    def populate_index(self,index,log_window,log_window_bundle):
        if index or log_window is not None:
            self.stack[index] = log_window
        elif log_window_bundle is not None:
            for index,log_window in log_window_bundle:
                self.stack[index]=log_window

    def increment_default_index_counter(self):
        self.default_index_counter = ++self.default_index_counter
```

There is also a controller which both creates, modifies, and passes values to the constructors of these 2 classes.

Log Controller/Coordinator:

```
from Log.Controllers.Routines.log_insert_log_entry_routine import insert_log_entry
from Log.Objects.log_entry_obj import LogEntry
from Log.Objects.log_window_obj import LogWindow
from Log.log_window_stack_instance import log_window_stack


def create_log_windows(log_window_indexs):
    log_window_bundle = {}
    if log_window_indexs is not None:
        for index in log_window_indexs:
            log_window_bundle[index] = LogWindow(index=index)
    return log_window_bundle


def create_log_entry(log_entry):
    return LogEntry(log_entry)


def insert_assigned_log_entries(log_window_entry_bundle=None):
    if log_window_entry_bundle is not None:
        for log_window_index,log_entry in log_window_entry_bundle.items():
            insert_log_entry(log_window_index,log_entry)


def distribute_log_entries(log_window_indexs=None,log_entries=None):
    if log_window_indexs or log_entries is not None:
        for index in log_window_indexs:
            for log_entry in log_entries:
                insert_log_entry(index,log_entry)


def push_to_log_window_stack(log_window_bundle):
    for index,log_window in log_window_bundle.items():
        log_window_stack.stack[index] = log_window


def present_log_window_stack(log_window_indexs):
    for index in log_window_indexs:
        log_window_stack.stack[index].show()


def window_index_exists(log_window_index):
    key_exists = False
    for key in log_window_stack.stack.keys():
        if log_window_index == key:
            key_exists = True
    return key_exists
```

Does this design look sloppy or riddled with potential errors down the line? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 2):

```
if model is not None:
```

You do this all over the place. You should change it to:

```
if model:
```

[`@property` is the Pythonic way to do getter and setters.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) For instance, I would do the following for the `model` variable:

Change:

```
self.model = model
```

To:

```
self._model = model
```

Create a property:

```
@property
def model(self):
    return self._model

@model.setter
def model(self, new_model):
    if new_model:
        self._model = new_model
    else:
        self._model = QStandardItemModel()
    self.setModel(self._model)
```

And do this for the other `set` functions.